# Can foreman handle nested subnets?

Tags: subnet, foreman, cidr

In Foreman 1.8 one can manage subnets through the web-interface at *Infrastructure > Subnets*. However, when I add a **/24** (e.g. 10.10.0.0 with a subnetmask of 255.255.255.0), I cannot add anything less specific below this subnet (e.g. a **/28** - 10.10.0.0 with a subnet mask of 255.255.255.240) as foreman claims that it "has already been taken". It seems that the checking mechanism is not taking the subnetmask into account.

Currently I use racktables to manage the subnets, but it would be convenient and less error-prone to migrate this part to foreman, too.

Is there a - preferably not too hacky - way to do this?

Comment: This sounds like a question best addressed in the Foreman documentation, to me.

Comment: You're probably right, but as they state at (http://theforeman.org/support.html) using serverfault w/ the foreman tag is as legitimate way to request support, I thought I'd give it a shot.

Comment: Ah I see - apologies, I wasn't aware that they were using ServerFault this way having not personally encountered many questions with that tag.